# How do I move data across grid using Wavemaker?

Tags: angularjs, spring, wavemaker

I have been using Wavemaker for a while now and trying to move data within the widget tab in the grid.? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The operation could be performed in two ways:

1. To move the selected items from grid1 to grid2,

   - enable the multiselect property of grid1 from the properties panel.
   - bind the grid2 dataSet value from the properties panel, to the selected item of grid1 from the widgets tab of the binding window

2)To move data across grids on a button,

- Click, Create a static variable of the required JSON format
- Drag and drop a button. Choose javascript action for the onClick event of the button as $scope.Variable..dataSet=$scope.Widgets.grid.selectedItems